# AWS websocket and cloudfront: WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 426

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to integrate cloudfront in front of apigateway websocket.
But when i try to connect my Client (HTML5) in the console im getting this error **WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 426**

In client I simply calling  `var ws = new WebSocket("wss://<id>.cloudfront.net");`

What could be my misconfiguration?

Thank you

Comment: What did you see in the logs on your origin server?  What was the CloudFront log entry corresponding to this request?

Comment: @lp-don Have you been able to solve this?